# Android device with hardware navigation bars pick correct layout

Tags: layout, uinavigationbar, screen-size

Would anyone please tell me how to make an android device with hardware navigation bars pick correct layout. I am using the following approach. Is this the correct approach? Is it possible by specifying some quantifier in the layout folder name.

```
        boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap
                .deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
        boolean hasHomeKey = KeyCharacterMap
                .deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);
        if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
            v = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_single_post, parent, false);
        } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
            if (hasBackKey && hasHomeKey) {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_single_post_hwkeys,
                        parent, false);
            } else {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_single_post, parent,
                        false);
            }
        }
```